# common component + common service in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I was wondering what is the correct location of a **common** UI-component that rely on a service in angular 2+ ?

It is clear that a common service (that do http calls) have to be located in core-module, and
a common component have to be located in shared-module,

but in my scenario what is the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this it's useful to take a look at the Angular Style Guide's [Overall Structural Guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#overall-structural-guidelines) section. The Angular team has some useful guidance on exactly this topic. For shared and core features they recommend creation of Modules. See 4-10 for more information.

Comment: How is your scenario different from the suggestion? Why can't you follow the style guide's recommendation? The question is not clear enough to define the need for the question.